# Sqlite via terminal

Tags: sqlite, terminal

New in sqlite and terminal commands,so may be this is simple.I was trying to create a DB table via terminal(studying)

```
sqlite> insert into game values ('fallout','rpg');
sqlite> insert into game values ('final fantasy','rpg');
sqlite> insert into game values ('gaame3','stealth');
sqlite> insert into game values ('hitman','rpg');
sqlite> select * from ame where type='rpg'
   ...> select * from game
   ...> 
   ...>
```

Created a table game  and load values into it.When i entered a query to see the data.i mistyped the name of the table and i got this

```
   ...>
```

How can i get back to the normal state ,Cntrl+Z worked but it changed back to the state where i started.Is there a way i can reach back to this.

```
sqlite>
```

without typing in

```
sqlite3 test.sqlite3
```

again

Comment: It's not that you typed the name wrong, it's that you forgot a `;` to terminate the line. Type that, and you should get back to where you were.

Comment: Oh that was the problem!!!.Thanks

Comment: @LithuT.V You can answer your own question. Then you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the problem:

to the problem.It is that i missed the `;` in the code entered so the terminal thinks the command  did not terminate.

Solution :

Add the `;` into the terminal and the new line of sqlite is open

Thanks [joachim-isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson) for the comments